# Export Google Tag Manager data?

Tags: json, api, tags, google-tag-manager

Does Google tag manager have a service for storing and returning data, preferably as json? I would like to backup some data to my server, without universal analytics.

Answer (score 1):

The only "data" GTM can return is the container file with your configured tags (so not really data in the sense of user data).

GTM is a Javascript injector; it does not track anything by itself and does not have any sort of persistent storage. You can use it to send data to an arbitrary endpoints and store the data yourself (doesn't have to be Google Analytics), but you cannot store data in GTM.

Comment: ok, i create some event and send it to GTM. What is the next step to return information back to the own server?